# Export multi user objects with armature

Tags: armature, export

Lets say I have 2 arm objects (Arm_1 and Arm_2). Their mesh is a multi user data. So that if I edit something in one arm the changes are applied to both arm objects.

I also have a single armature with bones and unique vertex groups for both arms. I have connected the armature with the arms and it is all animating properly inside Blender.

Now the problem is when I try to export all that. The exported FBX has only arm_1 visible and arm_2 is gone.

After some thinking I came to the conclusion (which might be wrong...) that the armature is being attached to each arm as a modifier. However since both arms are a multi user object, on export it applies the armature only to the first multi user object. And the rest are hidden.

How can I avoid this ?

I know I can make each arm a single user, but I like how convenient and easy it is to have them as multi object. If you need to go back and fix something, it is much easier to do it with a multi user data rather than to apply that change to each object separately.

Comment: Did you try to import it back to Blender? May be the other software not support multiple armatures in one file.

Comment: I have a single armature for both arms. Though when I imported it back to Blender both arms were there, but on top of each other. In the other program (Unity) the arms are on the proper location, but are invisible. If I remove the armature then they show up.

Comment: I kinda found a workaround. Every time before exporting I make a copy of all objects and then merge everything except the armature. Then export the merged copy